# Why is nuxt asking for @nuxt/typescript-build

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js

How do I fix this error -  "@nuxt/typescript-build not found"?

```
WARN  Module @nuxt/typescript-build not found. Please ensure @nuxt/typescript-build 
is in devDependencies and installed. HINT: During build step, for npm/yarn, 
NODE_ENV=production or --production should NOT be used.
```

The environment is AWS lambda, Node 14. Nuxt is installed with typescript, generated from npm.

Comment: Confirmed that some people add to production. I'm still trying to see if the code I have makes nuxt think it is in development mode. Likely to find out when I take it from uat to live. Stage is still dev which might be it.

Comment: It being a devDependency is just for the bundle size, nothing related to making Nuxt think that it's some kind of specific environment.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what this one is doing, but this is one of the required packages during the Setup. As shown here: https://typescript.nuxtjs.org/guide/setup#installation

```
yarn add --dev @nuxt/typescript-build @nuxt/types
```

Add this to your `nuxt.config.js` file

```js
export default {
  buildModules: ['@nuxt/typescript-build']
}
```

Create a `tsconfig.json` file and you should be good!

Comment: It is in dev, and too big to put into production. When deployed to production it still complains

Comment: Then, remove `--dev` to have it installed into your `package.json`'s dependencies and not `devDependecies`.

Comment: Exceeds the lambda storage lmiit.

Comment: What does this one mean? @Interlated

Comment: You are only allowed to have a 250Mb sized archive. Which is easy when this is 50mb

Comment: So, you cannot deploy it to production because `typescript-build` is to big? Or you need to remove a previous build for it? Didn't expect AWS to be so annoying.. Never had any issues on Netlify. Is your app that big?

Comment: The application is deployed ok. Just complains.

Comment: Even if the package is **NOT** in the `devDependecies`? Does it work if you build locally?

Answer (score 0):

If you're exceeding lambda storage limits checkout fume.app